# Alert Dialog and ASync Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

i am trying to use Alert Dialog Box and Async Task in the activity and am getting the following error

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside
>   thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

**Code:**

```
public class loginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public ProgressDialog loginDialog = new ProgressDialog(
            LoginActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        loginDialog.setMessage("Please wait Logging in");
        loginDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        if(loginUser()) {
            loginDialog.dismiss();
            alertbox("title", "winnn", "Okay");
        } else {
            loginDialog.dismiss();
            alertbox("title", "message", "Okay");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        loginDialog.dismiss();
        Intent intentHome = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentHome);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't update UI inside the `doInBackground()` method directly. (Yes if you still want to execute then write the same inside the **`runOnUiThread()`** method inside the `doInBackground()`)

Otherwise, do it inside the `onPostExecute()` method.

```
public class loginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
    public ProgressDialog loginDialog = new ProgressDialog( LoginActivity.this );
    public Boolean flag;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        loginDialog.setMessage("Please wait Logging in");
        loginDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if(loginUser())
          flag = true;
        else 
          flag=false;

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        loginDialog.dismiss();

        if(flag)
          alertbox("title", "winnn", "Okay");
        else
          alertbox("title", "message", "Okay");
    }
}
```

Comment: "You can't update UI inside the doInBackground() method." We can update inside the doInBackground() using runOnUiThread().

Comment: @LalitPoptani its already mentioned in answer before your comment :)

Comment: @PareshMayani ... what will happend if i use this code and i will change orientation when dialog is showing ?

Comment: @Selvin its different question, for that you need to write `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` inside the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

the onPreexecute and onPostExecute are part of the UI parts in the Async Task.. the doInBackground is a seperate thread so any thing done inside the doInBackground needs to be handled in the form of progressUpdate

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Example Reference: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

reflects any changes you need to make to the UI inbetween the doInBackground process.

Comment: He is facing problem for showing dialog from doInBackground().

Comment: yeah your answer seems good so i have no worries. intentions solved right